# Lebesgue Measure and Integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am interested in Lebesgue Measure and Integration.

so i have 2 questions. i want to learn that;

1) Can you explain me  a set that is measurable but is not Lebesgue Measurable?

2) How may i study Lebesgue Integration **without Lebesgue Measure Space?**

I read an article about it. Here is a referrence.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324331?origin=crossref&seq=1 you may look it.

another referrence is also https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-study-the-measure-theory-without-studying-Lebesgues-measure

May you give some details ?thanks.

Comment: Concerning your first question: what exactly is your definition of *measurable set*?

Comment: That's a simple question. Someone says intervals , single point sets like borel sets , Cantor Set, rational number sets etc as an example. But the right comment , there is a fact that Real Analysis is established on Measure Theory. Let  (X,A,μ) be a measurable space, A is a σ-algebra defined on X. so μ must be defined for every set in A. in these conditions  a subset E⊂X is a measurable set if and only if E∈A.

Comment: Then let $\mathbb R $ be equipped with its power set as $\sigma$-algebra so that *every* subset is measurable. If AC is accepted then it contains sets that are not Lebesgue measurable. The Vitali set for instance.

Comment: Thanks  for nice comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One route to Lebesgue integration without constructing the Lebesgue measure first is the Riez method where we first define the integral for step functions and then pass to functions that are the pointwise limit of step functions almost everywhere. The measure is then recovered by integrating the indicator function on a given set. A great book that covers this is [Lebesgue Integration](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lebesgue_Integration/Uzf0BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by *Soo B. Chae*.

Another route is the Lax method where we first consider the completion of the $L^{1}$ space prior to either the measure or the integral. This is covered in [Functional Analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Functional_Analysis.html?id=e_BjBAAAQBAJ) by *Peter Lax* as well as in [A Comprehensive Course in Analysis](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Real_Analysis/pkMACwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by *Barry Simon*.

As for your first question, the standard example of a set that is not Lebesgue measurable is the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Woow . That's a great comment .Thanks a lot:)